# Xcode 9.3 Compiling Swift source project never completes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9.2, xcode9.3

I updated my Xcode 9.2 to 9.3. Then after update, i used to compile my swift based project source, but it's not complete & no errors too.

Comment: did you try to restart your Mac

Answer (score 0):

check Project target whether you have signed in developer account?

complete clean the project then build and run.

shift+cmd+opt+k to clean the project and cmd+B to build.
 Try out this!!

Comment: @Jvvinoth Clean derived data folder and close xcode and reopen it then build and run

Answer (score 0):

Worked by changing Swift Language version Swift 3.3 to Swift 4.1 
(Build settings -> Swift Language Version)